# I am trying to read data from **API** and save it into Mongodb, But I have error undefined (reading '0')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
async function getdata() {
    const res = await fetch(**API**)
    const data = await res.json()

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const country = new Country({
            country: data[i].name.common,
            name: data[i].capital[0],
            latitude: data[i].latlng[0],
            longitude: data[i].latlng[1]
        })
        console.log(country)
        country.save()
    }
}

getdata()
```

I am trying to read data from **API** and save it into Mongodb But I have this error.
You can see the result on console, it means that I have what I need on Console but with this error.

[image]

Comment: Can you show `console.log(data)`?

Comment: In the image that you provide, there is no capital in your data, check the data object if it contains a capital or not

Comment: try to double check the data, if there is a missing attribute or not

Comment: @AhmedEl-Tabarani please check my comment  here is capital: [ 'Bern' ] can you check the image link in the question you can figher out what is going on

Comment: can you provide an image of the `data[3]`

Comment: it is too long i can not have it in one image but i have it there is no problem there

Comment: @sevagkhecho You should provide a complete sample object from your `data` by adding it to your question so that we can help you